# How to make an update image for a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit

I want to make a (firmware or application update or any update) update image for my raspberry pi 3, how do i go about doing that when i googled this same question I was quite confused with the results i read.
Could someone please point me in the right direction. I just was to try this OTA client(SWupdate) and eclipse hawkbit (Backend framework for software/firmware update rollouts to edge devices). How do you make a update a simple update image/binary file with a .swu extension so i can upload it to Eclipse hawkbit(the backend framwork for rolling out software updates through a webserver to edge devices) and then use SWupdate to actually run the update.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should first try to update a file rather than the whole image, to make a swu file you need a sw-description file in which you will describe all the parameters needed for the swu file, then you have to make a cpio file including the file that you want to upload, sw-description or if you have any other scrip to upload.

Then, install the swupdate client on your raspberry pi or whatever your machine is, start the webserver first and try to update the file using the webserver.

I would suggest you not look up hawkbit for now and just try to upload a file manually or using a web server and only then move on to the hawkbit because hawkbit itself is time-consuming and complex.